# How to convert an array of ids to array of hash with a key in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array,

```
array = [1,2,3]
```

Need to transform it to:

```
newArray = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]
```

I know this, Is there any efficient way?

```
array.each { |id| newArray << { id: id } }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything like this?

```
array.map { |id| Hash[:id, id] }
```

the same with hash literal

```
array.map { |id| { id: id } }
```

Answer (score 0):

A very elegant way:

- convert to string
- build the JSON style object
- convert to array (inside the string)
- let JSON parse it, for more (thread) safety
- symbolize the keys, because in ruby it's preferred to use keys rather than strings

additionally you could use Base58 random key and hash it twice to mitigate timing attacks

```
  JSON.parse([1,2,3].map(&:to_s).collect{  "{\"id\": \"#{_1}\"}" }.join(",").prepend("[").concat("]")).collect(&:symbolize_keys)
=> [{:id=>"1"}, {:id=>"2"}, {:id=>"3"}]
```